# Ng-init in the selection for default value with AngularJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selection, ng-options, ng-init

In web app I have a list of Expenses, which that if you press above it takes you to a new page to edit the selected Expense. When the user click on an element of list, I save the Object (the selected Expense) in a Global Object common in whole application and I retrieve it when I am in the Editing controller:

```
$scope.companySelected = GlobalApplicationData.selectedExpenseList;
```

The GlobalApplicationData.selectedExpenseList is an Object:

```
$$hashKey: "object:39"
_id: "33aa5549-7802-40d9-bc89-8780705b8c9b"
_rev: "3-eb940cb990524112723f711618e0cf51"
ad_table_id: 1000596
company_name: "Company 1"
data: Object
recordid: 1000005
__proto__: Object
```

In one expense there is only one company.
So, in this page of editing I have some field (input type text, date, etc). And I also have a `selection` with the list of the Companies of the logged user.  To retrieve that list, I made this function:

```
$scope.getCompanyList = function() {
    EditExpenseListSrv.getCompanyListDetail(user).then(function (companyListDetail) {
        $scope.companyList = companyListDetail;
        $scope.$apply();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

CompanyListDetail is an array of Obejct:

```
companyListDetail: Array[5]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

And this is one example of those object:

```
_id: "44e620dc-e715-453f-882b-3f21aeef48fe"
_rev: "1-c09c9f3350e853e588f3358aaafc0374"
ad_table_id: 1000146
data: {
    description: "text"
    id_company: 513424
    name: "Company 2"
}
recordid: 1000002
```

So the company of the selected Expense (`$scope.companySelected`) will definitely part of the list obtained by the query (`$scope.companyList`). But I want to give the user the possibility to change it. 
So I would like to make a `selection` containing the list (`$scope.companyList`) and default already selected the Company corresponding to `$scope.companySelected`.

I've writter this, but it doesnt work:

```
<select class="selection" ng-model="companySelected"
                          ng-init="companySelected = globalApplicationData.selectedExpenseList" 
                          ng-options="company 
                          as company.data.name for company in companyList">
```

But it doesn't work. I can see in the selection all the Companies, but don't select the default value

Comment: you need to assign that value in the `controller` instead of doing it in `ng-init`.

Comment: But I did writing $scope.companySelected = GlobalApplicationData.selectedExpenseList;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are assigning a default value to the `select`, you need to assign the object, so it won't work, when assigned with the same data of some other object:

*Note:*

*a) `data` is the array which is getting looped in the `select` list*

*b) `selectedcountry` is the model which is bind on `select` list.*

**Option 1:**

> Using `ng-init`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedcountry" ng-init="selectedcountry = data[0]" ng-options="item.name for item in data">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

[**Demo 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/f83eskLh/).

**Option 2:**

> Assigning the default from the `controller`

```
$scope.selectedcountry = $scope.data[0];
```

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/8uz3kpyp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the initialisation in the controller:

```
$scope.companySelected = "the value that you want to set here"
```

Or you can try to put the ng-init inside the parent of the select. Once I had a problem like this and I solved it putting the ng-init in the parent tag. Example:

```
<div id="parent" ng-init="companySelected = globalApplicationData.selectedExpenseList">
    <select ...>
</div>
```

Another idea would be to put companySelected inside an object. I have had some problems (I am not sure why) with the forms if I was using $scope.value inside the ng-value instead of using $scope.formData.value